# Getting error : "Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead "

Tags: flutter, dart

Im trying to build flutter web app on release mode using `flutter build web`(also tried `flutter build web --no-sound-null-safety`).When i do,im getting the below error.

```html
D:\saves\reset_password>flutter build web

Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety

Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning: The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
.dart_tool/flutter_build/1916f9367c0e6ad6c929bd88cf5227e5/web_plugin_registrant.dart:14:38:
Error: Null safety features are disabled for this library.
void registerPlugins([final Registrar? pluginRegistrar]) {
                                     ^
Error: Compilation failed.


Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             44.9s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

It works fine when i run it directly in debug mode using `flutter run`.
Note: I recently upgraded to flutter 3.0 and im using Android studio.
Below is my `flutter doctor`( i am aware of the android tools missing.since im building for web,i didnt pay much attention to it)

```html
D:\saves\reset_password>flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel master, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.966, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.8.5)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I fixed this error by myself.Here's what i did:

I found that there are few dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` file that are not used currently.I navigated to my `.dart_tool\flutter_build\cb8031cdd1bfbcb95122aae4ad9a63d5\web_plugin_registrant.dart` and found that those dependencies are being referenced inside `registerPlugins()`.

I cleared all those unused dependencies shown in `registerPlugins()` and did the following steps:

1.`flutter pub get`
2.`flutter clean`
3.`flutter build web`

And VIOLA! The error went away and i got my files in the `build\web` folder.

Comment: I had the same issue today after transferring projects from an intel laptop to m1. I only needed to do `flutter clean`; then build worked.

Comment: So just running "flutter clean" allowed you to run flutter build web without errors?  I tried that and it didn't work for me.

Comment: The real issue here is that the code generator for web_plugin_registrant is using null safe features, even when building without null safety.

Comment: @MatthewPatience I had the plugin well before null safety was introduced in Flutter.So thats not the issue.

Comment: Hey @vasanthkumar , what version of flutter are you using? I reported this issue to the Flutter team a couple days ago and they did in fact confirm it as a severe issue that is affecting the beta and master channels. The issue is that the web_plugin_registrant is using null safe code features, even for projects that don't support it. Here is the issue report for tracking: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/109160

Comment: The issue @MatthewPatience started has been fixed and merged. But I'm still having this issue on `Flutter 3.0.5 • channel stable`.

Comment: @skillitzimberg yes the PR fix was merged to master but is not yet in beta or stable channels. I have submitted a cherry pick request to try and get it in the next beta release.

Comment: @skillitzimberg the fix is now in stable with 3.3.0

Answer (score 11):

For me was launching  `flutter clean && flutter pub get` on the cmd/terminal, the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.
It was on server based on Ubuntu.

In my case I had:

Target dart2js failed: Exception: Warning:
The 'dart2js' entrypoint script is deprecated, please use 'dart compile js' instead.
flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth_web-3.3.19/lib/firebase_auth_web.dart:402:16:
Error: The method 'FirebaseAuthWeb.verifyPhoneNumber' has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'FirebaseAuthPlatform.verifyPhoneNumber'.
...

I discovered that a firebase_auth_web dependency had a deprecated version and wasn't used in the project. Hence I removed this dependency. After that the problem disappears.

Answer (score 1):

Delete `/flutter/bin/cache` folder.

Run `flutter doctor`.

Then, run `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and `flutter build web`.

Answer (score 1):

in case you're using old version of flutter, it's probably because old dependency

you can run this to upgrade dependencies that still works in your flutter version

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Answer (score 0):

`flutter build web` worked on my local but not on my server, after `sudo reboot` it worked again. the above sugestet answer didnt work for me...

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is now available on the stable channel 3.3.0. It was due to a change in one of the 3.0 builds that put null safe features in the web plugins registrant. Any web project without null safety would have been affected.

Answer (score 0):

Delete .dart_tool

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter build web
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the dependency that is giving the error